# Using groupby for user id and combining strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, preprocessor

I'm having trouble with preprocessing data. I have data that looks like

I want to group by a field that denotes the user called Account Number, and I want to create a new field that is a concatenation of all values of Customer Event Type for each Account Number.

I've tried this:

```
df_by_accnum = df.groupby('Account Number')[['Customer Event Type']].agg(','.join).reset_index()
```

but it results in all the column names being concatenated instead of hte values (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Um0aU.png)

Could I get some help trouble shooting this? Thank you

Comment: I just tried this and it doesn't work, I get: KeyError: "Columns not found: 'Customer', 'Event', 'Type'"

Comment: my bad, I thought you had three fields! bottom line is that you need to provide a [mcve]. Can you at least include a sample of the contents of `df`?

Comment: I have 31 variables, of which only 2 are of concern: Account Number and Customer Event Type, both of which are strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By try and error I found out that it might be due the type of the column *Customer Event Type*. I guess it might hold non string values, which *join* assumes, and for some reason the column names are used instead.

Try creating a new column converting *Customer Event Type* to strings and use that one:

```
>>> d = {'Account Number': [1, 2, 3, 1], 'Customer Event Type': [1, 1, 2, 2]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>> df['Customer Event Type str'] = df['Customer Event Type'].astype(str)
>>> df.groupby('Account Number')[['Customer Event Type str']].agg(','.join).reset_index()
   Account Number Customer Event Type str
0               1                     1,2
1               2                       1
2               3                       2
```

Whereas using the numeric column produces:

```
>>> df.groupby('Account Number')[['Customer Event Type']].agg(','.join).reset_index()
   Account Number                                Customer Event Type
0               1  Account Number,Customer Event Type,Customer Ev...
1               2  Account Number,Customer Event Type,Customer Ev...
2               3  Account Number,Customer Event Type,Customer Ev...
```

Hope it helps. Let us know if you find out the reason for this behavior. Thanks!